# ASP.Net Core RC2 cannot find config.json

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm updating my ASP.Net Core project from RC1 to the recently released RC2. One problem I am facing is loading the `config.json` file into the configuration object in `Startup.cs`.

My project fails to start and throws the `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception when it fails to find `config.json`.

Here's the working code from RC1

```csharp
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()       
        .AddJsonFile("Settings/config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

Here's the almost identical code in RC2, which does not work. Note that I've moved the `config.json` file up a level just-in-case it was folder hierarchies that were causing the failure.

```csharp
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
}
```

(N.B. I've tried with and without the `SetBasePath` call.)

One option is to replace `.AddJsonFile("config.json")` with these two lines

```csharp
.AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
```

That does prevent the `System.IO.FileNotFound` exception but only by making the file load optional, it still seems to fail to load.

To debug what is happening I've added a `FileInfo("config.json")` and the file exists. I've tried using the full name from that `FileInfo` object and I still get the exception.

How do I load the `config.json` in RC2, or how do I diagnose its failure to load?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/009a062fc6dd2a49ccef376d1c0e3ca47e252577/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/JsonConfigurationExtensions.cs I wonder if for some odd reason it's not getting the `PhysicalFileProvider`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `WebHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot` method call  before building `IWebHost` instance.

Example:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```